# woocommerce: Customize email with item total count

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, theme-development, woocommerce-offtopic

i looking everywhere, but not found this functions, i need to calculate the total items in the report email new order,i think is (admin-new-order.php)
so i need to see `the numbers total products` in the under row on subtotal or elsewhere

[image]

```
Item                       Price                       Quantity             
------------------------------------------------------------------
Product A                      $10                         4                
Product B                      $5                          1      
Product C                      $15                         2                 



Cart Totals

Cart Subtotal       $30
Count products      7 <---
Shipping Cost       $12

Order Total         $42
```

How i do ? Help..me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could call either of the following functions in your email template:

```php
<?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count(); ?>
```

OR

```php
<?php echo(count(WC()->cart->get_cart())); ?>
```

Comment: from functions.php its possible?

Comment: You wanted to do it in your email template right? Use them in your email template/any page template that you want. There is no point in echoing them in functions.php, you could use them in functions.php though but you don't need to! Echo them in your theme templates.

Comment: ok i now try, but there is also the possibility to add from functions.php?